# One unique id for different tables

Tags: mysql, database

In mysql i have two tables. Two tables both has auto increment. I want the tables share same unique id table. For example when i insert a data to table 1 it will give id 5 to row, end then table 2 wont be able to use id 5. It automatically give id 6 to row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one unique key in two different tables, why dont you merge the table?
If you can't then the Simplest step would be to remove the `AutoIncrement` constraint from the second table, and insert on it based on the Id generated on the first Table

Comment: It is not possible because actually I got more than two tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP to generate the next number then it's not difficult, the SQL below will give you the current highest number from both tables, PHP can compare and add 1 to the highest before writing it back to the appropriate table.

SQL:-

SELECT MAX(  `table1`.`ID` ) AS  `table1id` , MAX(  `table2`.`ID` ) AS  `table2id` 
FROM  `table1` ,  `table2`

But you will want to turn off the auto-increment, IF you can't merge the tables then another method would be a third table with 2 fields

table1 fields ID, Whatever field list

table2 fields ID, Whatever field list

table3 fields ID, table1.ID or table2.ID in non unique field

Table3 then becomes the index for either of the other two.